# How do I raise my weapon (hold-up)/shoot while moving?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater, metal-gear-solid-2-sons-of-liberty

In Metal Gear Solid 2 and Metal Gear Solid 3 (on all platforms), how do I raise my weapon (hold-up) and/or shoot while moving? I am seeing people do this all of the time in videos of MGS2 or MGS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's different in each game - Playstation(Xbox)

MGS2 - Hold Square (X) strongly on a non-automatic weapon and GENTLY for automatic weapons to hold it up without shooting, Hold L1 (Left Trigger) to freely run around while aiming (while running and aiming in this mode, Snake and Raiden will auto-aim at the center of a nearby target)

MGS3 - You can run and aim by default by holding Square (X) GENTLY, Snake will raise his weapon without firing it, using the movement stick will cause him to move instead of aim like in MGS2. Holding L1 (Left Trigger) will now change the movement scheme so that it works as an "FPS" game where you will strafe left and right instead of turning Snake's body.